# Passing byte array to lua script method from C++

Tags: c++, lua, arguments, arrays, parameter-passing

How can i pass a byte array as an argument to lua script method from C++ code?
Are only int, float or string data types allowed?
Also how can i retrive byte array from lua script method?
I will pass a raw byte array to script. It will parse and use it.
Thanx.

Answer (score 5):

Depends what you want to do. Lua strings are immutable byte arrays, so if they're small you're probably best off simply turning the byte array into a string with `lua_pushlstring` and passing it in like that --- yes, embedded \0 is supported and works fine. But because they're immutable Lua will end up copying the string every time you want to modify it, so it may not be suitable for your requirements.

Other options are:

- copy the data back and forth between your C++ byte array and a Lua array (that is, table of  numbers). This will be fairly expensive in memory, but is probably the easiest way.
- wrap you C++ byte array in a lightuserdata and provide Lua bindings to let you access it directly. This is the most efficient, but is quite a lot of code.

Answer (score 2):

Int and float values will be converted to Lua's number type (by default, `double`).

If the script itself just needs to keep a pointer to pass between functions, blobs of C data are usually pushed as light userdata:

```
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, bufptr);
```

When passing arrays of bytes to Lua, strings are normally used (strings of arbitrary data can be created using `lua_pushlstring`):

```
lua_pushlstring (L, bufptr, buflen);
```

This will create an immutable string in Lua, which can only be modified by creating new strings.

If you need to work with mutable byte buffers in Lua (not recommended- low-level byte manipulation is what C was designed for and Lua was not), the best bet is to create a userdata type for the buffer with methods to get and set tailored to the use case (individual positions as numbers, ranges as strings or tables of numbers).